# Proof of equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have just started my math class and I think I might not be completely understanding the 3 properties of a equivalence relation: reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity.

I have these 2 examples and I would like to know if my steps are good or what I am missing.

What would be the main difference by the bigger or equal to 0 and bigger than 0?

Knowing $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$:

**A.** **$a \sim b$ if $ab \geq 0$**

for reflexivity: $a\sim a$ if $a^2 \geq 0$ then yes

for symmetry: $a \sim b$ if $b \sim a$  then $ab \geq 0$ if $ba \geq 0$ then yes

for transitivity: $a \sim b$ if $b \sim a$ then $a \sim c$ then $ab \geq 0$ if $bc \geq 0$ if $ac \geq 0$ then no

**B.** **$a \sim b$ if $ab > 0$**

for reflexivity: $a \sim a$ if $a-a=0$ so yes

for symmetry: $a \sim b$ if $b \sim a$ then $a - b = c \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $b - a = -c \in \mathbb{Z}$ then yes

for transitivity: $a \sim b$ if $b \sim a$ then $a \sim c$ Here I have no idea how to prove it

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Well, for the second one, $0\not \sim 0$ so it isn't reflexive.

Comment: when does the 0 ~ O come from?

Comment: Sorry?  under the second relation $0$ is not equivalent to itself, since $0^2$ is not greater than $0$.

Comment: I just edited, but @GooseLooking in the future please write your questions using the MathJax typesetting. Thank you and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the second carefully, then you can do the first yourself. Define $a \sim b$ if and only if $ab>0$.

- **Reflexivity** means $a \sim a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a \sim a \iff a^2 > 0$ which is only true if $a\ne 0$, hence the relation **is not reflexive**
- **Symmetry** means $a\sim b \iff b \sim a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a\sim b \iff ab > 0 \iff ba > 0 \iff b \sim a$, so indeed the relation **is symmetric**
- **Transitivity** means $a\sim b, b\sim c \iff a \sim c$ for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ then 
  $$
  \begin{split}
  a\sim b,b\sim c 
    &\iff ab>0,bc>0\\
    &\iff a,b \text{ have same sign and } b,c \text{ have same sign}\\
    &\iff a,b,c \text{ all have the same sign}\\
    &\iff ac > 0 \\
    &\iff a \sim c,
  \end{split}
  $$
  so the
  relation **is transitive**

Comment: So it isn't reflexive bc it can't be applied to all value of a? (since a != 0)

Comment: @GooseLooking correct, it must be true for all values of $a$

Comment: Ok perfect. For symmetry, if a or b =0, then it can't be symmetric, correct? bc 0 is in ℤ, so how can we say for sure ab>0 ?

Comment: Symmetry means that for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, you have $a \sim b \iff b \sim a$. Now note that $a \sim b \iff ab > 0 \iff b \sim a$, so it *is symmetric*, since if $a=0$ or $b=0$, then $a \sim b$ does not hold...